# facebook invite example can run simulator but not run iPhone device

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-invite

facebook app invite:

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content = [[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
NSString *appLink = [@"https://fb" stringByAppendingString:@".me/176327329406660"];
content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:appLink];
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
```

simulator run well, but iPhone device is not.

the errose app invite error:

> Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=9 "(null)"

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs in devices, it will not occur in simulator, try below steps may that solve your problem:

sign out from Facebook from iPhone Settings/Facebook on your phone.

- Go to seeting of your phone
- Open facebook setting
- Allow facebook interaction in facebook settings.

Comment: only app invite can not open InviteDialog.share and login is ok on device and simulator